# Integration by sampling from truncated distribution

Tags: self-study, sampling, numerical-integration, truncated-normal-distribution

I'm reading the [book](https://benlambertdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/bayesianbook_problemsanswers_final.pdf) Ben Lambert's *Bayesian Statistics: problems and answers*, which by the way I like.

There  is a group of problems in "Integration by Sampling" chapter 12.

The first integral is

$$ \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} x^6 \cdot \frac{\exp (-\frac{x^2}{2})} {\sqrt{2 \pi}} \,dx $$

It is recommended to notice that this statement is equal to $\mathbb{E}(x^6)$ and to sample from $x \sim N(0, 1) $. Then it is straightforward to get sample mean $\frac {1} {n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} x_i^6$. Its value is around 15.

So far so good.

It is the next similar problem where I stuck. The difference is that now integral is from the same but **truncated** distribution (see integration limits).

$$ \int^{\infty}_{1} x^6 \cdot \frac{\exp (-\frac{x^2}{2})} {\sqrt{2 \pi}} \,dx $$
The answer in the book suggests to do the same procedure but with truncated version. This doesn't help much as $\mathbb{E}(x)$ is obviously larger in this case but the integral is smaller. (I suspect that there is an error in the book but it is not the point of the question).

**Question.** Are there ways how *truncated distribution* can be helpful in principle in such cases where we can see nice distribution to sample from?

(Notice also that it is *not* the question about homework. I can get this integral as numerically, so by rejection sampling. Its value is around 7.5, not 47 as book suggests. I'm asking because I miss some conceptual understanding of the matter).

Comment: the book has a bit different formula in the example, namely, it has $x^3$.

Comment: @garej, I think there is the typo too. All other examples use $x^6$ and follow the same logic.

Comment: The truncated integral is not an expectation, because the function $\exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is not a valid probability density on the interval $[1,\infty):$ it lacks the normalization constant.  What prevents you from applying your first solution by sampling from the standard Normal distribution restricted to $[1,\infty)$?

Comment: "MMA" would be what, exactly?  If it's a procedure (and not just black-box software), you can't blame it, because you get to determine what you do!